# java code coverage with jacoco

Tags: java, code-coverage, jacoco

I have a next project structure

```
src/main/java/com/Example.java
src/main/java/com/ExampleMapper.java
```

i need to get code coverage for `ExampleMapper` without `Example` class. I write in `pom.xml`

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.1.201405082137</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>report</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>report</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <includes> 
        <include>com/example/**/*Mapper.class</include>
      </includes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

But, i got `0%` as coverage output.

Hot to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change it to this:

```
<include>com/example/*Mapper*</include>
```

Then, Jacoco works correctly.